# How to write csv file with \t as separator? straightforward way doesn't work

Tags: java, csv, encoding

I use the following code to write a csv file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "aa\tbb\tcc\tdd";
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\test\\test.csv")), "UTF-16LE");
    writer.append(str);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

when I open the file in excel, the columns are not separated. They are all in one column.
I open the file in notepad++ and see that its encoded with 'UCS-2 LE w/o BOM'.
If I save the file encoded with 'UCS-2 Little endian' and them open it in excel, the columns are separated .

How can I write the file in java in this encoding so that it will show separated columns in excel?

Comment: You can also use what you're doing but save the file with a .tab extension, then Excel will recognize tabs as the delimiter.

Comment: have you seen http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20fjava.nio.charset.Charset) ?

Comment: I didn't know that about the .tab extension!  Good one!

Comment: Also see the following website:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081953/write-text-file-in-ucs-2-little-endian-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa writer.write("\uFEFF");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma instead of a tab, e.g.

```
String str = "aa,bb,cc,dd";
```

I don't believe Excel separates data columns delimited with Tabs by default.  You can do it but it takes an additional step.

Comment: which step?
can't I encode the file in java in the same encoding that I use in notepad++ in order to make the file readble?

Comment: In my version of Excel, under the Data menu, there's a Text to Columns button.  That brings up a wizard where you can choose the delimiter between columns, e.g. tab.