# Python Writing a UCS-2 Little Endian (utf-16-le) file with BOM

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

I have a 3rd party app that reads in a Unicode file of utf-16-le. For some reason it has to have a BOM or it won’t read the file.

I had a lot of difficulty writing an output file of this encoding so I thought I’ll document my solution here for others who might come across the same issue.

```
import codecs

mytext = "Help me"

with open("c:\\temp\\myFile.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
    f.write(mytext.encode('utf-16-le'))
```

I was seriously misled by the chosen [‘correct answer’](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5202815/510937) in the following thread.

```
write('\ufeff')
```

Does not write the required BOM marker into the file (at least it didn’t for me using Python 2.7) 
You need

```
write('\xff\xfe')
```

I don’t have enough reputation to post that so I’m posting my own 
[Adding BOM (unicode signature) while saving file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202648/adding-bom-unicode-signature-while-saving-file-in-python)

I think this is the exact same issue in Java 
[Write text file in UCS-2 Little Endian, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081953/write-text-file-in-ucs-2-little-endian-java)

Comment: @Bakuriu
When I was googling for "UCS-2 Little Endian" I didn't hit that answer. took me a lot of looking to find that. I posted this here in hopes that someone else can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 7):

```
import codecs

mytext = "Help me"

with open("c:\\temp\\myFile.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
    f.write(mytext.encode('utf-16-le'))
```

Comment: I could not test on Python 2, for Python, we need to open the file with `"wb"`

Comment: Yes, it should be "wb".